# issue with making a specific type of json

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

An API I'm using need this specific format when I try anything else I get a 200 but without it actually working

```
{
    "things": [
        {
            "awdad": "awd",
            "234": "234234",
            "234234234": {
                "name": "Jon",
            },
            "wadadw": {
                "234234234": "awdawd",
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

what I tried to do is this

```
$data['things'] = [
    'awdad' => 'awd',
    '234' => '234234',
    '234234234' => [
        'name'=>'Jon',
    ],
    'wadadw' => [
        '234234234'=>'awdawd',
    ],
];
```

after JSON encoding it gave me this

```
{
    "things": {
        "awdad": "awd",
        "234": "234234",
        "234234234": {
            "name": "Jon"
        },
        "wadadw": {
            "234234234": "awdawd"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need another layer of array inside `things`.

Comment: enclosed it with another `[]` after `=` and after `],`